# React Native SVG - (iOS) Invariant Violation: Native component for "RNSVGSvgView" does not exist

Tags: ios, svg, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm having an issue with the SVG library for React Native running on iOS simulator.

[image]

```
"dependencies": { 
     "better-fetch": "^1.1.2", 
     "firebase": "^4.8.1", 
     "lodash": "^4.17.4", 
     "react": "16.0.0", 
     "react-native": "0.51.0", 
     "react-native-svg": "^6.0.1-rc.1", 
     "react-redux": "^5.0.6", 
     "redux": "^3.7.2", 
     "redux-logger": "^3.0.6", 
     "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0" 
}
```

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
npm install react-native-svg --save //(again)
react-native link react-native-svg //(again)
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install
```

[image]

Comment: All I can advice is that your project is fubar. Try that your recipe over and over again: unlink, remove pods, uninstall node_modules, do some black magic. And then do the opposite in correct order. And if it still hangs, remove library references manually from XCode and then add them manually back. In one project a while ago, we had the very same nuisance with RN-SVG and managed to fixed it like that.

Answer (score 3):

The image obviously shows that the problem is in the linking. As a result, If automatic linking does not work for you, it is possible to try manual linking. The guide for manual linking is missing for IOS devices; however, it is missing for IOS.

But you can follow the following steps for manual linking on IOS:

1. Open your project in XCode
2. go to .../node_modules/react-native-svg/ios
3. Locate and drag the file `RNSVG.xcodeproj`, into library directory shown in XCode.
4. Expand the file you just added (`RNSVG.xcodeproj`) until you see libRNSVG.a, it is located in `RNSVG.xcodeproj > Products`)
5. Drag `libRNSVG.a` into the Link Binary With Libraries section (located in Build Phases which may be found at the top of the XCode window)

Now you are good to go:)

Comment: Thank your very much for your complete answer, I had this problem on IOS linking for a long time, and this method worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. Restarting `Xcode`, the simulator, and rebuilding the target seemed to fix it in my case.

I used the automatic linking process:

```
npm install react-native-svg --save  
react-native link react-native-svg
```